# Как добавить текст в зашифрованный файл, и прочитать и удалить текст перед расшифровкой

Tags: c#, шифрование, aes

Мне нужно добавить какой-нибудь текст (в файл, любой не только текстовый, размер файла от 1 кб до 100 мб) как в начало и по желанию в конец зашифрованного файла, как это можно реализовать в этих методах?

Метод шифрования:

```
public static void AES_Encrypt(string inputFile, string password)
{
   try
   {
      byte[] passBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
      byte[] saltBytes = new byte[12];
 
      using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
         using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
         inputFileStream.CopyTo(tempStream);
         tempStream.Position = 0;
 
         using (var outFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Create))
         using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
         {
           rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 256;
           rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 256;
           using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passBytes, saltBytes, 1000))
           {
              rijndaelManaged.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.KeySize / 8);
              rijndaelManaged.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8);
           }
           rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
           using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outFileStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
           {
               tempStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
           }
         }
      }
    }
    catch  { }
}
```

Метод расшифровки:

```
public static void AES_Decrypt(string inputFile, string password)
{
      try
      {
         byte[] passBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
         byte[] saltBytes = new byte[8];
 
         using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
             using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
             inputFileStream.CopyTo(tempStream);
             tempStream.Position = 0;
 
             using (var outFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Create))
             using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
             {
               rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 256;
               rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 256;
               using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passBytes, saltBytes, 1000))
               {
                 rijndaelManaged.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.KeySize / 8);
                 rijndaelManaged.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8);
               }
               rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
               using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(tempStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
               {
                  cryptoStream.CopyTo(outFileStream);
               }
             }
           }
        }
     }
     catch { }
}
```

Comment: Что нужно - понятно, а что именно не получается?

Comment: @aepot, Я не могу понять как мне текст добавить :) Чёт вообще туплю

Comment: Что за текст и куда? И зачем? Давайте конкретнее. Файл текстовый? Файл большой по размеру? В зашифрованный или расшифрованный? Если в зашифрованный, текст надо шифровать, или нет?

Comment: @aepot, В любой файл, текст допустим: `text` чтобы можно было ориентироваться по этому названию, в зашифрованный файл передаём текст `text` сам текст не шифруется, после в расшифровщике этот текст нужно найти, удалить чтобы успешно расшифровать методом декрипта файл. Вот так вот.

Comment: Какой максимальный размер файла? Ваши методы имеют с этим проблемы, так как читают весь файл в память.

Comment: @aepot, А это будет иметь проблемы если размер файла слишком большой? Ну для тестирования максимальный размер файла у меня 10 МБ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вдаваясь в подробности, вот решение с записью сигнатуры в начало файла.

```csharp
private static readonly byte[] signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TEXT");

public static void AES_Encrypt(string inputFile, string password)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] passBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[12];

        using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
                inputFileStream.CopyTo(tempStream);
            tempStream.Position = 0;

            using (var outFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Create))
            using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                outFileStream.Write(signature, 0, signature.Length);
                rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 256;
                rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 256;
                using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passBytes, saltBytes, 1000))
                {
                    rijndaelManaged.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.KeySize / 8);
                    rijndaelManaged.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8);
                }
                rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(outFileStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    tempStream.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}

public static void AES_Decrypt(string inputFile, string password)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] passBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[12];

        using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
                inputFileStream.CopyTo(tempStream);
            tempStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] testSignature = new byte[signature.Length];
            int bytesRead = tempStream.Read(testSignature, 0, signature.Length);
            if (bytesRead != signature.Length || !testSignature.SequenceEqual(signature))
            {
                return; // сигнатура не найдена
            }

            using (var outFileStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Create))
            using (var rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 256;
                rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 256;
                using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passBytes, saltBytes, 1000))
                {
                    rijndaelManaged.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.KeySize / 8);
                    rijndaelManaged.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8);
                }
                rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(tempStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    cryptoStream.CopyTo(outFileStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

**Потенциальные проблемы:**

- Файл полностью читается в память при расшифровке и шифровке, могут возникнуть проблемы с `OutOfMemoryException` при работе с большими файлами.
- Данный в методах `try-catch` полностью гасит все исключения, то есть вы никогда не узнаете, если при работе с файлом возникла ошибка. Так делать не рекомендуется.
- В исходных методах несоответстве длины массива соли, то есть пара методов не рабочая, я исправил.

Comment: А можно ли сделать проверку на то что, существует ли в данном файле (который шифруется/расшифровывается) текст: `"TEXT"` ?

Comment: Значит для записи используется `outFileStream.Write(signature, 0, signature.Length);` но если после этого открыть файл в блокноте то текста `"TEXT"` там нету, там всё зашифровано. А в расшифровщике используется: `tempStream.Position = signature.Length;` это он получает начало после нашего текста, но не удаляет его?

Comment: @ZidoX и если нет, то что делать?

Comment: если нет что? Я просто подумал что после записи в файл в начале будет типа `TEXT` после зашифрованный текст, и чтобы расшифровать файл сначала нужно было удалить этот `TEXT` в начале файла, я об этом изначально думал

Comment: @ZidoX обновил ответ, добавил проверку

Comment: Благодарю, за такой ответ! Спасибо большое за помощь, очень выручили! Всё работает замечательно как и нужно. Подскажите а как ещё в конец файла записать? по такому же принципу да?

Comment: @ZidoX в конец файла сложнее, потому что нужно будет криптострим тормозить не на конце файла, а раньше, и с ходу я не знаю, как это сделать. В смысле, дописать в конец легко, а вот считывать - сложнее. Потом будет странно выглядеть, что вы открываете поток, и сразу идете в его конец для чтения.